# Adjective for something coming in from all directions and corners

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

**Adjective** for something coming in from all directions and corners.

[*adjective*] influx of people.

[*adjective*]  pressure overwhelmed him.

Comment: Would either "360-degree" or "full-circumference" work?

Comment: I'd suggest **omnidirectional** but it tends to be associated more with electronic signals....

Comment: I would say *overwhelming*, but you've already used that word.

Answer (score 2):

onslaught

He almost made it out of the meeting, but there was an onslaught of questions that kept him there for an hour.

Answer (score -1):

"implosive" I guess. Implosive comes from implosion which is somewhat related to compressing something inward from all directions.